# How do I wake up a thread at a specified time in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, locking, manualresetevent, nscondition

I'm writing an ssh wrapper in objective-c, I'm trying to implement a maxTime a command should take to execute.  The way I implement it is:

**Main Thread:**

1. calculate timeout
2. create asyncThread (GCD queue) to execute command and parse the returned data
3. waitForTimeoutOrSignal
4. return result

**AsyncThread:**

1. execute command
2. get returned data
3. if received correct data signal MainThread

In C# I had good success using ManualResetEvents to signal the MainThread. In Objective-C the closest class I can find is NSCondition but it seems that it's not built for inter-thread communication.

In fact I get:

> 2012-05-22 00:31:05.761 libssh2-for-iOS[60821:11303] ** -[NSCondition
>   unlock]: condition ( '(null)') unlocked from
>   thread which did not lock it
>
> 2012-05-22 00:31:05.763 libssh2-for-iOS[60821:11303] ** Break on
>   _NSLockError() to debug.

when I try to use it.  Is there another way to use NSCondition or a better way for a thread to sleep until it receives some sort of signal?

Comment: There are about 20 ways (ok, maybe an exaggeration, but a half-dozen) to send a timer event of some sort to a thread.  But the most important thing to know is that the main thread should never wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok turns out that I was almost right.  My problem (as the compiler handily alluded to) was that I was locking in one thread and unlocking in another.  What really solved it was learning about the "signal" method in NSCondition.  So now I've rewritten the code thusly:

**Worker #1 Thread:**

```
[NSCondition lock]
start worker thread
if([NSCondition waitUntil:maxTime])
    // got signal
else
    // timed out
[NSCondition unlock]
```

**Worker #2 Thread:**

```
Do work
[NSCondition signal]
```

Comment: Waiting (beyond a few milliseconds) in the main thread is a no-no.

Comment: You are right Hot Licks, have updated example to Worker Threads #1 and #2